# Wildfly Thorntail fails to deploy due to Operation timed out awaiting service container stability

Tags: java, spring, jboss, thorntail, wildfly-18

Wildfly Thorntail timeout and fails to deploy.

It takes very long to try and deploy - Am not sure if there is a hanging thread somewhere during the deployment -

Note: I have checked the Database connections looks good

See the stack trace.

What could be causing the below issue - I have tried to increase the deployment time on JVM options but still doesn't work

```
-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=600
```

```
2021-02-24 17:31:38,960 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) AMQ221007: Server is now live
2021-02-24 17:31:38,961 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.10.1 [default, nodeID=5c5674a4-76b5-11eb-b97e-005056867aa6] 
2021-02-24 17:31:39,179 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
2021-02-24 17:31:39,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYCLINF0002: Started passivation cache from web container
2021-02-24 17:31:39,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0002: Started default cache from server container
2021-02-24 17:31:39,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started passivation cache from ejb container
2021-02-24 17:31:40,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2021-02-24 17:31:41,328 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/RemoteConnectionFactory
2021-02-24 17:31:41,344 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
2021-02-24 17:31:41,537 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-7) AMQ151007: Resource adaptor started
2021-02-24 17:31:41,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-7) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
2021-02-24 17:31:41,550 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]
2021-02-24 17:31:41,550 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0118: Binding connection factory named java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory to alias java:/JmsXA
2021-02-24 17:31:44,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2021-02-24 17:31:44,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9910/management
2021-02-24 17:31:44,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9910
2021-02-24 17:31:44,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Thorntail 2.7.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) started in 44760ms - Started 412 of 638 services (409 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2021-02-24 17:31:56,721 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying management-console-ui.war
2021-02-24 17:31:56,977 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "management-console-ui.war" (runtime-name: "management-console-ui.war")
2021-02-24 17:32:12,809 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.management-console-ui.war" is using a private module ("io.smallrye.metrics") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2021-02-24 17:32:12,829 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.management-console-ui.war" is using a private module ("org.infinispan") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2021-02-24 17:32:12,830 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.management-console-ui.war" is using a private module ("org.infinispan.commons") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2021-02-24 17:32:12,830 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.management-console-ui.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.jts") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2021-02-24 17:32:12,830 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.management-console-ui.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2021-02-24 17:32:13,364 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2021-02-24 17:32:15,755 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/console' for server 'default-server'
2021-02-24 17:32:16,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "management-console-ui.war" (runtime-name : "management-console-ui.war")
2021-02-24 17:32:18,147 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs] (main) TTJAXRS0001: Unable to parse web.xml while searching for javax.ws.rs.core.Application servlet mapping:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.api.DescriptorImportException: Could not import XML from stream
2021-02-24 17:38:03,627 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying admin-frontend-war.war
2021-02-24 17:38:03,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "admin-frontend-war.war" (runtime-name: "admin-frontend-war.war")
2021-02-24 17:43:03,648 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[("deployment" => "admin-frontend-war.war")]'
2021-02-24 17:43:03,653 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "admin-frontend-war.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: "WFLYCTL0344: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability"
2021-02-24 17:43:08,655 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$1@5615fb7b for operation add at address [("deployment" => "admin-frontend-war.war")] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:523)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1518)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1472)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1445)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:876)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:423)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:289)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.10.4.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:255)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl$LocalClient.executeInModelControllerCl(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:259)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl$LocalClient.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.lambda$executeInVm$0(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.access.InVmAccess.runInVm(InVmAccess.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.executeInVm(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.access$000(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl$1.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.LocalModelControllerClient.execute(LocalModelControllerClient.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.LocalModelControllerClient.execute(LocalModelControllerClient.java:39)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.client.AutoCloseable$Closeable$ModelControllerClient$1295808720$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:287)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:476)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:747)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)

2021-02-24 17:43:13,663 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[("deployment" => "admin-frontend-war.war")]'
2021-02-24 17:43:13,666 ERROR [stderr] (main) org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: WFLYCTL0344: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability
2021-02-24 17:43:13,667 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,667 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,667 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,668 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,668 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:476)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,668 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:747)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,668 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,669 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,669 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,669 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,669 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,670 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,670 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,670 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: WFLYCTL0344: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability
2021-02-24 17:43:13,671 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2021-02-24 17:43:13,671 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
2021-02-24 17:43:13,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0099: Unbound non-transactional data source: java:jboss/datasources/AstDS
2021-02-24 17:43:13,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2021-02-24 17:43:13,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0119: Unbinding connection factory named java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory to alias java:/JmsXA
2021-02-24 17:43:13,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/default]
2021-02-24 17:43:13,867 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/RemoteConnectionFactory
2021-02-24 17:43:13,868 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
2021-02-24 17:43:13,869 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0008: Undertow AJP listener ajp suspending
2021-02-24 17:43:13,942 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:9443
2021-02-24 17:43:13,952 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0007: Undertow AJP listener ajp stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8010
2021-02-24 17:43:13,980 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/console' from server 'default-server'
2021-02-24 17:43:13,981 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.impl.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN000029: Passivating all entries to disk
2021-02-24 17:43:13,982 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.impl.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) ISPN000029: Passivating all entries to disk
2021-02-24 17:43:13,994 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
2021-02-24 17:43:13,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped default cache from server container
2021-02-24 17:43:14,033 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.impl.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) ISPN000030: Passivated 0 entries in 50 milliseconds
2021-02-24 17:43:14,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped passivation cache from web container
2021-02-24 17:43:14,035 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.impl.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN000030: Passivated 0 entries in 53 milliseconds
2021-02-24 17:43:14,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped passivation cache from ejb container
2021-02-24 17:43:14,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0011: Unbound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]
2021-02-24 17:43:14,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:/AdnDS]
2021-02-24 17:43:14,041 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2021-02-24 17:43:14,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
2021-02-24 17:43:14,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = mysql
2021-02-24 17:43:14,543 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) AMQ151003: resource adaptor stopped
2021-02-24 17:43:14,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment management-console-ui.war (runtime-name: management-console-ui.war) in 974ms
2021-02-24 17:43:16,196 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.10.1 [5c5674a4-76b5-11eb-b97e-005056867aa6] stopped, uptime 11 minutes
2021-02-24 17:43:16,203 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2021-02-24 17:43:16,205 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8120
2021-02-24 17:43:16,207 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.0.27.Final stopping
2021-02-24 17:44:00,003 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."admin-frontend-war.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."admin-frontend-war.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container is down
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:260)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2065)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:260)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2065)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.server@10.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:227)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more

2021-02-24 17:44:00,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment admin-frontend-war.war (runtime-name: admin-frontend-war.war) in 56357ms
2021-02-24 17:44:01,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0050: Thorntail 2.7.0.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) stopped in 47527ms
2021-02-24 17:44:06,076 ERROR [stderr] (main) org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: WFLYCTL0344: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability
2021-02-24 17:44:06,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,076 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,077 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,077 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,077 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:476)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,077 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:747)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,078 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,078 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,078 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,078 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,079 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,079 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,079 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,079 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: WFLYCTL0344: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability
2021-02-24 17:44:06,080 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:runtime@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,080 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
2021-02-24 17:44:06,080 ERROR [stderr] (main) java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
2021-02-24 17:44:06,080 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:914)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,081 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:346)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,081 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getEntry(ZipFile.java:1120)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,081 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry0(JarFile.java:576)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,081 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:506)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,082 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:468)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,082 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.JarFileResourceLoader.getJarEntry(JarFileResourceLoader.java:187)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,082 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.JarFileResourceLoader.getClassSpec(JarFileResourceLoader.java:130)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,082 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:330)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,083 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,083 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,083 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,083 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,083 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,084 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,084 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.stop(Swarm.java:438)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,084 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.tryToStopAfterStartupError(Swarm.java:779)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,085 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container:api@2.7.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:756)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,085 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,085 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,085 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,086 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,086 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:57)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,086 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:134)
2021-02-24 17:44:06,087 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by something in the application. Does the application have some code that executes during startup, such as `@Startup` EJBs? You may also want to try updating to Thorntail 2.7.0.Final. (But also note that Thorntail has reached its end of life: https://thorntail.io/posts/the-end-of-an-era/)

Comment: I don't seem to have @Startup annotation - however this seem to have occurred after MySQL Database was stopped and started again. Then for some reason when i deploy it hangs trying to make a connection.

Comment: Hmm yea that sounds plausible, but I'd expect some kind of a database-related exception to be thrown as well. You didn't paste the entire log, so not sure, but -- do you have any other exception in the log?

Comment: I have updated the startup log with the exception -and also updated to thorntail to 2.7.0 and still getting the same. Am using java 11. Is the a way to update/ prolong or increase the deployment timeout in project default yaml config?

Comment: I just noticed that even the deployment of `management-console-ui.war` takes unusually long, based on the log timestamps. I vaguely recall that we've seen some issues like this a while ago, I think it was on Windows with some antivirus software, which made file access very slow. (Thorntail unpacks the entire uberjar into a temporary directory, which can be a lot of files.) If you're on Windows, can you try running the app on a Linux machine?

Comment: It is running on linux machine - The issue seemed to be caused by a low memory space on the server. Even though i had specify JVM heap space to be used - it required more.
So my artifact was very big - I decided to unbundle some of the unnecessary big files and put them in a filesystem. Just to try and decrease the size of the artifact built through maven,  
That then significantly improve the build and thorntail can now deploy without having to face timeout issues.

Comment: Great to hear that!